# Disk Image (img) cannot mount

Tags: disk-image

I have made a disk image file of `/dev/sda1` partition which has windows xp recovery environment. The file is 20.1 GB stored on a `ext4` partition, when I am going to open it with the tool of `disks` app to mount disk images, it says the following:`Error opening /media/george/Storage/sda1.img` : Value too large for defined data type.

(my language on ubuntu is greek, so I translated it from google translate). What does it means? Is the file too large to be mounted? Does it have any problem because it is made from a manufacturer partition designed for restoring windows xp?

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit system? (If you're not sure, see System Settings/Details).

Comment: Hint for your language problem to avoid bad google translations: You can run a single command in the default fallback language (usually English) by typing `LANG=C ` before the actual command in terminal. Example: `LANG=C sudo apt-get update` You can also start GUI applications like gparted in English this way: `LANG=C gparted-pkexec&` (gparted-pkexec is the executable name, & frees the terminal - it would belong to gparted otherwise and exiting the terminal window would also kill the GUI application)

Comment: +Byte Commander Even though you are free to use the terminal for other stuff if you use the `&`, exiting the terminal would still kill the process. If you use `LANG=C nohup > /dev/null gparted-pkexec &`, you can then safely close the terminal.

Comment: +Hitechcomputergeek Actually, an even better way is to use `LANG=C setsid gparted-pkexec`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a relic called `ulimit`.  For fun enter `ulimit -a` to see what's going on.

If you bump into any limits try `ulimit -f unlimited` and give it another go.  More information about this forgotten and mostly unnecessary gem is found in the man page.

Edit:  A bit more information is down this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471564/what-does-ulimit-s-unlimited-do, but you want the **file** flag, which is `-f`.

Edit: and that would be `sudo ulimit -f unlimited` unless you are already root, but you probably knew that.